# How to get a real time notification of Questions posted in SO for a particular tag

Tags: discussion, notifications

Is it possible to get real time notification of new questions being posted on SO for a particular tag.

I have tried Google Reader but it is not realtime. Are there any real time Feed readers for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll get is the normal (non-realtime) feed.  Click on the tag you're interested in and scroll to the very bottom of the page for the link.  Here's an example for the c++ tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

There's an RSS feed for the tags page - subscribe to the feed on this page for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

replace the last bit with the tag of your choice.

Comment: There is a per-tag rss. C#, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23&sort=newest

Comment: @Joel - Just revisited the answer as you were commenting.