# Is it possible to be notified of new questions with particular tags?

Tags: support, tags, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a real time notification of Questions posted in SO for a particular tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43456/how-to-get-a-real-time-notification-of-questions-posted-in-so-for-a-particular-t)

I'm interested in answering questions on the few topics that I know something about, but they are somewhat infrequent. Is there a way to get an email notification of new questions with particular tags? Or that match a search?

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to tag specific RSS feeds, for example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby-on-rails
```

You might be able to use this as a basis for E-Mail notification using a 3rd party service.

Comment: Trying out http://www.feedmailer.net/ for this

Answer (score 2):

Set up an email subscription to any Stack Exchange site tags here:

https://stackexchange.com/filters

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/