# How to get notification when a question using a specific tag is asked?

Tags: discussion, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to be notified of new questions with particular tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53077/is-it-possible-to-be-notified-of-new-questions-with-particular-tags)

I would like to get notified when a new question is asked under,e.g., [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) tag on Stack Overflow.

What should I set in my profile to get notified by email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you add [StackGuru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stackexchange-sites) to your favourite Jabber / XMPP client (e.g. Google Talk). You can use it to 'follow' specific tags (such as WCF), which would give you near real-time IM notifications for new questions on them.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an email subscription to any Stack Exchange site tags here:

https://stackexchange.com/filters

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/