# How do I get notified when some questions are posted in my interested area?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to be notified of new questions with particular tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53077/is-it-possible-to-be-notified-of-new-questions-with-particular-tags)

I subscribed to some tags, such as [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), but I'm not getting any notification when new questions are posted under those tags.

Is that the correct way?